# Parameterized test suite

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a bunch of parameterized JUnit4 tests which all look like:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyTestX {
  private final MyParameter param;
  public TestX(MyParameter param) { 
    this.param = param; 
  }

  @Test
  public void myTest() {
    // Some test code
  }
}
```

I want to run them from different test suites, each with a different value for MyParameter.

I tried the following:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses( { MyTest1.class, MyTest2.class, ... })
public class MyTestSuite1 {

  @Parameters
  public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    Object[][] data = {{ new MyParameter(1) )}};
    return Arrays.asList(data);
  }
}
```

But it does not work: I get "No public static parameters method on class MyTestX".

Is there a way to specify the parameters from the test suite instead of the testcase?
I would like to avoid creating a new class for each test, for each test suite, if possible.

Comment: I think that to achieve that you'd have to extend both Suite and Parameterized runner classes in order for the former to capture parameter data and pass it to child runners, and for latter to receive the parameter data not from the annotated method, but from the Suite runner.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar problem. it was fixed by creating an abstract class that contained the `@Parameters` and `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`. this class was extended by all the tests in the test suite. one of the things i found out is that `@Parameters` will be call before `@BeforeClass` and `@Before`, whether these annotations are inside your test suite or your test. hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting to run *different* tests with the same parameters.

Parametrized testing is for running the *same* test with different parameters.  If your tests aren't exactly the same, then you need different tests.

What you need to do is add different `@Test` methods to your `MyTestX` class and forget about parameterized testing.  Then you'll only have one class, and your tests will be organized in a clear fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I am learning Junit and WebDriver and during my practice of junit, I also got the similar error. Not sure how much useful my answer would be but worth giving a try.

Please check your import statement and should have correct parameters statement i.e. **import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters**;

if it collides with any other parameters statement then try removing the other statement and keeping this statement only.

This solved my issue.

Just saw this post is 2 yrs old but this might help anybody else getting the same issue now.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run them from different test suites, each with a different value for MyParameter.

Your requirement is different to the normal behaviour of `Parameterized`: If you define a hierarchy of tests and assign the same set of parameters (`Object[][]`) to them, the JUnit framework will run tests with all parameters for the first test case, before it goes over to the next test case and runs it with all parameters.

So **if you want to execute all tests for a single parameter first** before going over to the next parameter, **you need another runner**. Have a look at [this library](https://github.com/PeterWippermann/parameterized-suite) that provides you with the `ParameterizedSuite` Runner.

A parameterized test suite looks like this:

```
@RunWith(ParameterizedSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses({OneTest.class, TwoTest.class})
public class MyParameterizedTestSuite {
    @Parameters(name = "Parameters are {0} and {1}")
    public static Object[] params() {
        return new Object[][] {{'A',1}, {'B',2}, {'C',3}};
    }
```